# Build an Objective-C/Metal app from the command line

Tags: command-line, build, xcode-project

I have created a Mac OS app project in Xcode to draw a simple 2D triangle and it works fine.

However, now I want to build it on command line but I am confused on how to do it as the code is in Objective C and it makes calls to METAL which is implemented in C++.

I have worked with gcc and g++ before.

Can someone please direct me to some command line build tools for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build Xcode projects from the command line you can use `xcodebuild`.

> xcodebuild builds one or more targets contained in an Xcode project, or builds a scheme contained in an Xcode workspace or Xcode project.

This tool is included in the Xcode command line tools and has a man page (just execute `man xcodebuild` in Terminal) explaining the basic usage.

Comment: are you familiar with any debugging tools as well ? does gdb/lldb work ?

Comment: No, sorry. I am just using it to build.